# undefined index error in login form

Tags: php, mysql, forms

I have started to learn php and mysql and I have created a login form.
I want to show error when username or password is incorrect. But when the page is opened it shows Notice: Undefined index: user and  Undefined index: pass, and i have included the php code below the password input box because I want to show the error below it, but I keep getting this error.And if I enter any wrong username and click on login then this error doesn't appear. Please help

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<form action="login.php" method="post">
<label for="username">Username</label>
<input name="user" type="text" id="username" required="" >
<label for="password">Password</label>
<input name="pass" type="password" id="password" required="" >
<?php
// start session
session_start();
include'connect.php';
// Define $username and $password 
$username=$_POST['user']; 
$password=$_POST['pass']; 
$sql="SELECT * FROM table WHERE username='$username' and password='$password'";
$result=mysqli_query($con,$sql);
// Mysql_num_row is counting table row $count=mysqli_num_rows($result);
// If result matched $username and $password, table row must be 1 row
if($count==1){
$_SESSION['username'] = $_POST['user'];
// goto to welcome page
header('Location: welcome.php');
}
else {
// show error
echo "<div style='color:red;' class='errorbox'>Incorrect Username or Password</div><br>";
}
?>
<button type="submit">Log In</button>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: When you load the page for the first time your post data does not contain user or pass . So you should check whether it exists before using it.

Comment: @ck_arjun I entered if(isset($_POST['user'])) below include connect.php not it doesn't shows undefined user error but shows the pass error and also one new error undefined username

Answer (score -1, accepted):

you need to format your script like below.

```
<?php
//start session
session_start();
include'connect.php';
// Define $username and $password
if(isset($_POST["user"])) {
    $username   = mysqli_real_escape_string($_POST['user']); 
    $password   = mysqli_real_escape_string($_POST['pass']); 
    $sql        = "SELECT * FROM table WHERE username='$username' and password='$password'";
    $result = mysqli_query($con,$sql);
    $count      = mysqli_num_rows($result);
    if($count==1) {
        $_SESSION['username'] = $_POST['user'];
        // goto to welcome page
        header('Location: welcome.php');
    }
    else {
        // show error
        echo "<div style='color:red;' class='errorbox'>Incorrect Username or Password</div><br>";
    }
}
?>
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<form action="login.php" method="post">
<label for="username">Username</label>
<input name="user" type="text" id="username" required="" >
<label for="password">Password</label>
<input name="pass" type="password" id="password" required="" >
<button type="submit" name="login-now">Log In</button>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

**points to be noted**

1. `session_start();` needs to be started before everything, there should not be any html code before it.
2. use of condition with `isset` which indicates the submit button is clicked and value of `post` is set, if it is set, it means the other requests of username and password is also ready to request.

(if you directly execute statements without `isset`, the requests won't be ready to request, and if requested, it returns with an error, `undefined index`)

3. As a reminder by @Alex, user of `mysqli_real_escape_string`, this protects your script with SQL injections.

Comment: never ever check with `isset($_POST["submit"])`, as it is not reliable.

Comment: okay, what would be the better condition then @ksno?

Comment: checking anything else.. in theory you wouldnt want to submit an empty form so there would always be a required field.

Comment: it is not a safe solution.

Comment: you mean `isset($_POST['user'])` ?

Comment: thanks for the reminder @AlexS, i updated, yup it is required.. :)

Comment: `mysqli_real_escape_string` is not safe and deprecated in PHP 5.5.0, and it was removed in PHP 7.0.0. Learn howto prevent against injection: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php . I suggest to have a look at Zaffy's answer

Comment: @ameenulla0007 now I am getting this error Warning: mysqli_num_rows() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, boolean given

Comment: @MahimParsai http://www.w3schools.com/php/func_mysqli_num_rows.asp check the link, you will get an idea, where you went wrong..

Comment: Often that error is due to a invalid query @MahimParsai

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
// start session
session_start();
include'connect.php';
if (!empty($_POST)) {
    // Define $username and $password 
    $username=$_POST['user']; 
    $password=$_POST['pass']; 
    $sql="SELECT * FROM table WHERE username='" . mysqli_real_escape_string($username) . "' and password='" . mysqli_real_escape_string($password) . "'";
    $result=mysqli_query($con,$sql);
    $count=mysqli_num_rows($result);
    // If result matched $username and $password, table row must be 1 row
    if($count){
        $_SESSION['username'] = $_POST['user'];
       // goto to welcome page
       header('Location: welcome.php');
    } else {
       // show error
echo "<div style='color:red;' class='errorbox'>Incorrect Username or Password</div><br>";
    }
} 
?>
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<form method="post">
<label for="username">Username</label>
<input name="user" type="text" id="username" required>
<label for="password">Password</label>
<input name="pass" type="password" id="password" required>
<button type="submit">Log In</button>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

The more safe solution, with anti session fixtation and anti SQL injection:

```
<?php
if (!isset($_SESSION)) { session_start(); }

include'connect.php';

if(isset($_POST["user"])) {

    $username = bin2hex(htmlspecialchars($_POST['user'])); 
    $password = bin2hex(htmlspecialchars($_POST['pass'])); 

    $query = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT id, username FROM table WHERE username=UNHEX('$username') AND password=UNHEX('$password')");

    if (mysqli_num_rows($query) === 1) {
        $result = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query);
        $_SESSION['username'] = $result['username'];
        $_SESSION['userid'] = $result['id'];
        session_regenerate_id();
        header('Location: welcome.php');
    } else {
        echo "<div style='color:red;' class='errorbox'>Incorrect Username or Password</div><br>";
    }
}
?>

<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<form action="" method="post">
<label for="username">Username</label>
<input name="user" type="text" id="username" required="" >
<label for="password">Password</label>
<input name="pass" type="password" id="password" required="" >
<button type="submit" name="login-now">Log In</button>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Remember to HASH your passwords (with a salt, and don't use md5)